# Is there a Fate equivalent to the D&D Beginner box?

Tags: fate, system-introduction

I have the opportunity to run an RPG at the local Library games day, which carries with it some stipulations:

1. The players are likely new to pen & paper RPGs entirely. (And if they're not, they're almost certainly new to Fate since it's not well known around here.)
2. I likely have people for 2 hours, and it won't be a recurring game (as it's an introduction), so I can't spend an hour helping people create characters and the setting on the spot.
3. Given the nature of the event, I won't know who is playing in advance, or their ages (except that they're pretty unlikely to be younger than 12).

Other people have run games like D&D at these before, so I want to run Fate to showcase something different, and because I think it'd be a hit with people here if they get to try it out. The difficulty I'm having is that while D&D has the beginner box, for example, I haven't found an equivalent that really says "if you're new to the game, play this first to get an idea of how things all work."

I don't need a fully written adventure, although I'm not opposed to that. All I really need is a starting point, with a setting set up with some basic goals and premade characters that I can then let people customize and then turn loose. I have seen some published settings from Evil Hat, but given my criteria it's hard to know which of them would work and which wouldn't, as I have no experience with any of them.

It's also worth mentioning that I'm a newbie to Fate as well, and haven't run it at all. I intend to do that with friends a coupe of times before going to the library though. In the case of my friends, as I know exactly who is playing, it was easy to decide on a setting (Pinkie Pie's zany adventures).

Comment: *Two hours* to teach people how to play pen & pencil RPGs **and** try to get in a decent one-shot? Good luck...

Comment: Do you want to use Fate Core or is any Fate game okay?

Comment: And what about FATE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The first chapter of the Fate Core rules are designed to be a quick introduction to game concepts**; It contains just enough information to get started as a player. **There's also a "cheat sheet" that summarises commonly-referenced rules** in the back of the book.

As for a starting adventure, I understand that there are a number of example adventures and campaigns around ([like these ones](http://www.evilhat.com/home/fate-worlds-and-adventures/)), but as recommendation questions are now considered off-topic on this site, I won't discuss their relative merits and disadvantages. Alternatively, you could make your own starter adventure, which would allow you to keep things simple for your target audience.

(To be honest, I suspect that two hours is too short a time to both introduce the concept of role-playing games and to get actual play time in; I'd want at least five hours for that. But that's just me.)

Comment: This is what we ended up using, rules wise. Setting wise, we took the same setting we'd used in our last D&D game and just did some conversions, so everyone already understood the setting. That made it easy to get a story going initially. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3):

Fate Accelerated Edition is a good start -- it's a cut down version of Fate Core with just 6 "approaches" (Careful, Quick, Forceful, Sneaky, Flashy, and Clever) instead of the more typical 24-ish skills for a Fate game.  Using Fate Accellerated Edition, the players just need to rank the 6 approaches (allocating a +3, two +2s, two +1s, and a 0), pick a name, a central Aspect, and use the simplified stunt rules to come up with at least one stunt to get started.

To go even faster, you want to either make pre-gens, or use the excellent "It's not my fault" mini-expansion(http://www.drivethrucards.com/product/162084/Its-Not-My-Fault-A-Fate-Accelerated-Character--Situation-Generator), which gives cards that provide a role and a stunt (helping players decide on which Approaches to favor) and also include a lovely situation generator where players explain how the situation isn't their characters's fault, but some other character's fault and how, thus creating the initial situation and a basic relationship web.

Answer (score 0):

You can ever try *Fate Accelerated Edition*.  They streamlined the system as much as possible, turning it very simple. 50 pages and you can work it in 30 minutes

Comment: Please expand your answer to explain what qualities make FAE a suitable solution to the querent's question.

Comment: They streamlined the system as much as possible, turning it very simple. 50 pages and you can work it in 30 minutes

Comment: That's a great start! Edit it into your answer and directly address the specific points in the question and how FAE meets or fails to meet them. If you have experience using FAE this way, draw on that in addressing the querent's concerns. (Comments are for figuring out how to improve a post, but they're ephemeral things that can't be relied upon to stick around themselves.)

Comment: I'll... But I'm commuting to work

Comment: It'll still be here when you have the time to answer it fully.

Comment: @BESW Forgot to say: FAE is good if you know what are you doing as a GM. If you're a newbie, maybe you should compliment it with some setting. Some of the bests IMHO for FAE are (in no specific order) _Do - Fate of the Flying Temple_, _Young Centurions_, _Strays_, _Masters of Umdaar_, _Nitrate City_ and _Good Neighbors_

Answer (score 0):

FAE is good if you know what are you doing as a GM. If you're a newbie, maybe you should compliment it with some setting. Some of the bests IMHO for FAE are (in no specific order) *Do - Fate of the Flying Temple*, *Young Centurions*, *Strays*, *Masters of Umdaar*, *Nitrate City* and *Good Neighbors*